# Importing a ZIP file to Dialogflow Agent gives "Language " not supported by platform" error

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to restore a backup agent to a new agent in Dialogflow. I've gone to my existing agent and exported with no problem.

But when I go to restore it to a new agent I get this error:
[DF Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STLYA.png)

I've opened up the zip file and looked into the agent.json and it looks like the agent key is set properly:

```
  "description": "Allow your app to engage in small talk about a variety of topics.",
  "language": "en",
  "shortDescription": "Small talk topics to help make your bot more personable",
  "examples": "User: Hello!\nUser: How are you?\nUser: Thank you!\nUser: You\u0027re welcome.\nUser: What\u0027s up?\nUser: I\u0027m bored.\nUser: I\u0027m joking.\nUser: Well done!\nUser: Who are you?\nUser: How old are you?\nUser: You\u0027re clever.\nUser: What do you do for fun?",
```

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2):

Update: I reached out to support and was able to get this solved. For some reason my agent did not have the "lang" key populated in all the intents, even though it worked just fine in the existing agent.

Dialogflow support fixed the issue in my agent and emailed me the correct zip file.